# Table layout continue expanding under other elements fixed at the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a table layout inside a relativelayout. the relativelayout contains the table at top, and another linearlayout at the bottom. When i add more rows to the table it gets bigger till it takes all the screen size, then the scroll view that contains the table rows starts working!
here is the layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/WHITE" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout2_general_horizantalscrol"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView_report_rows"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/WHITE"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablelayout_general_scrollview_row"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</TableLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout_general_Itemname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center" >
    </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout_general_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center" >
    </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout_general_total"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center" >
    </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout_general_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center" >
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the scrollview inside the first tablelayout to start working when reaching the linear layout. Or in other words, I want the first tablelayoud not to take the full screen space to expand in, and leave some for the linear layout. I want my app to run in portrait and landscape orientations, and on several screen sizes, so I don't like to hard-code height values.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding android:layout_above to your table layout.

```
<TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
            android:layout_above="@+id/id_of_bottom_linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/WHITE" >
```

Don't forget to assign the same id to the bottom aligned linear layout.
As an aside, your layout seems to use too many table layouts which can affect performance.

Comment: It did't affect the behavior :(